# Select Two Unique Random From Array while Are not Equal to a Given Value

Tags: php

How can I select **two unique** random from and array and check that it **are not equal** with one pre-selected (default value)? For example I have an array of months like

```
 $months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
```

and a given month `$alreadyin = "Feb";` now I need to select two unique months which are not equal to `$alreadyin`?

```
<?php
    $alreadyin = "Feb";
    $months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    $rand_months = array_rand($months, 2);
?>
```

Comment: compare `$rand_months` with `$alreadyin`. If it's in, do array rand again. You can put it in a while loop that only exits when two uniques are generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute the difference (get months that are not `$alreadyin`) and then select 2 at random:

```
$rand_months = array_rand(array_diff($months, [$alreadyin]), 2);
```

You could also search for and remove `$alreadyin`:

```
unset($months[array_search($alreadyin, $months)]);
$rand_months = array_rand($months, 2);
```

`array_rand` returns random keys from the array, so you may need something like:

```
foreach($rand_months as $key) {
    echo $months[$key];
}
```

To get the actual month names using the first example, shuffle the array and slice 2:

```
$months = array_diff($months, [$alreadyin]);
shuffle($months);
$rand_months = array_slice($months, 0, 2);
```

Or using the second example:

```
unset($months[array_search($alreadyin, $months)]);
shuffle($months);
$rand_months = array_slice($months, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Abra but why I am getting associated array instead of name of months?

Comment: Because `array_rand` returns the keys, I was just using what you had.

Comment: Great answer. `array_rand()` returns random indices. You'll need to add a final step to index into the original array using each of the returned indices like `$rand_months = array_map(function ($e) use ($months) {
    return $months[$e];
}, array_rand(array_diff($months, [$alreadyin]), 2));`

Comment: but the output looks like `[0] => 3     [1] => 8` instead of  `[0] => Mar     [1] => Aug`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple process. Get random values, check if they match, repeat if they don't.

```
function getUniqueMonth( $alreadyin ) {
    $months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    while( true ) {
        $rand_months = array_rand( $months, 2 );
        if ( !in_array( $alreadyin, $rand_months ) ) {
            return $rand_months;
        }
    }
}
```

You can always add a counter for safety, to make sure the computer doesn't keep looping forever.